# How to get servername in Yii index file

Tags: php, yii

How can I get domain name(server name) in index.php file of Yii ? I want to detect the subdomain name from it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Same as any other php file. If you wanted to you instead do it in your config file and store it as a param so you could access it at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

`CHttpRequest` is the class you need, it encapsulates $_SERVER variables;

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest
```

The function you will need is CHttpRequest::getBaseUrl() (should not be called statically) 
see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getBaseUrl-detail
if the app is loaded you call it by using `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)`

The advantage of using this method instead of `$_SERVER` directly being that `CHttpRequest` resolves inconsistency of how `$_SERVER` is handled among different Web servers.

Also note that you can obviously call a Yii class after the framework is loaded; so when you are using CHttpRequest in index.php ensure it is after Yii classes are loaded;

It is **strongly recommended** you do *not* add any logic like this on index.php - this file is literally called for each and every request; Your subdomain is after all not going to change on every request

You can directly call `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)` in your controller or in a `RunonceCommand` and use `parse_url` and `explode` to get subdomains with this

```
//Works for multiple subdomains like 'http://sub1.sub2.example.com' as well;
public function getSubDomain($url){
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    $hostPart = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);
    $subdomains = array_slice($hostPart, 0, count($host) - 2 );
    return $subdomains;
}
```